# How NOT to print "getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed" when getEmbeddedPicture fails

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am trying to create a Flutter plugin for getting file metadata from a file whit the possibility of it not having an `embeddedPicture`. Whenever I call the `getEmbeddedPicture` method and it fails it prints out the message : "getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed" which contributes to some lag.

I want to know how to stop the printing of that message if the method call actually fails.

**EDIT :** I tried catching it but with no use, the message still appears and the `catch` block is not called.

Comment: This is either because the developer missed this method when removing debugging code, or perhaps hadn't figured out what to put there. Have you tried talking to the developer?

Comment: @NomadMaker, I am the developer, and I don't have any debugging code that I know about.

Comment: So you wrote getEmbeddedPicture()?

Comment: No, getMebeddedPicture is part of android mediaReceiver, they wouldn't leave debug code after shipping it

Comment: Talk on some specialized Android forums. It does sound like debug code. It should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but depending on your IDE you could probably filter them out.

Comment: They still show up on my release build, my problem is not with the IDE

Comment: Yes like I said you can’t remove it.